# React-trello not installed to react JS project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, trello

I'm trying to install `react-trello` in my **react js** project. But I got an error while installing this trello using `npm` in my visual studio code. I am referred to this article **[Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-trello)** and perform step by step procedure.

**I tried this code:**

> npm i react-trello

[image]

Comment: Did you found the solution?